# why does wrapping functions in iife cause weak types?

Tags: polymorphism, ocaml, iife, reason, value-restriction

I'm trying to figure out a way to hide certain helper functions and related stuff from the user of a module and thought using an IIFE would work, yet it fails because a type variable cannot be generalized?

I think I've boiled it down to the most basic scenario with the following code:

```
module TestA = {
  let y = 0;
  let x = (type a, numbers: list(a)): option(a) => None;
};

module TestB = {
  let x =
    (
      () => {
        let y = 0;
        (type a, numbers: list(a)): option(a) => None;
      }
    )();
};
```

In TestB the compiler complains with

```
  41 │ };
  42 │ 
  43 │ module TestB = {
  44 │   let x =
   . │ ...
  50 │     )();
  51 │ };
  52 │ 
  53 │ module Number = {

  The type of this module contains type variables that cannot be generalized:
  { let x: list('_a) => option('_a); }

  This happens when the type system senses there's a mutation/side-effect,
  in combination with a polymorphic value.
  Using or annotating that value usually solves it. More info:
  https://realworldocaml.org/v1/en/html/imperative-programming-1.html#side-effects-and-weak-polymorphism
```

why is that? And how could I approach the problem of hiding `y` from the user of the module?

P.s.: When reformatting the return type annotation in `TestB` gets put behind the `None` like so: `(type a, numbers: list(a)) => (None: option(a))`. Why here and not in module `TestA`? As far as I understood it this just "tags" the returned value, so I don't see a difference here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You hit what is called the [value restriction](https://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/polymorphism.html#sec56). In short, the compiler thinks there may be potential side effects happening inside the closure that might unsafely change the return type of the function. So it can't safely decide on a return type.

Fortunately, ReasonML has an easy, idiomatic replacement for IIFEs–[brace-delimited scopes](https://reasonml.github.io/docs/en/syntax-cheatsheet#blocks-1):

```
module TestA = {
  let x = {
    let y = 0;
    numbers => None;
  };
};
```

This scope hides `y` inside the definition of `x`.

The more general way to hide items in a module is by giving the module a signature that simply does not list the hidden item(s). In this case it would look like:

```
module TestA: {
  let x: list('a) => option('a);
} = {
  let y = 0;
  let x = numbers => None;
};
```

Another way would be to use an 'interface file', e.g.:

```
// TestA.rei
let x: list('a) => option('a);

// TestA.re
let y = 0;
let x = numbers => None;
```